# Setting up a callback for the DatetimepickerBundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, datetimepicker

I use the [DatetimepickerBundle](https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle) in my Symfony project. In one form I have two date fields, `start` and `end`. I want the end field to update automatically when the start field is changed, so the user doesn't have to select the date again, since most events will have their start and end on the same day.

The Bundle is based on the [bootstrap-datetimepicker by smalot](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and generates the following javascript for each field:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $field = $('#app_bundle_event_start');

    $field.datetimepicker({"formatter":"js","format":"dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii","autoclose":true,"language":"de"});  
});
```

I added the following code in the template, but it doesn't do anything.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#app_bundle_event_start').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
        $('#app_bundle_event_end').datetimepicker('update', ev.date);
    });
}
```

If I don't wrap it in the document-ready callback, the end-date is updated, but on the start-date field the datetimepicker is re-initialized and loses all its options.

How can I add this event callback to an already initialized datetimepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, although I am not 100% sure, that `.on()` actually belongs to standard `jQuery` event. Basically, you do not need to call `datepicker()` again.

So, to attach callback to already initialized `Datepicker` just do:

```
$('#app_bundle_event_start').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $('#app_bundle_event_end').datetimepicker('update', ev.date);
});
```

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :)